# What would be an alternative to running Twig for loop inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, symfony, highcharts, twig

I'm new here.

I am trying to make a graph using highcharts library. It works when I give it one element, but when I want to give it a lot of elements with lot's of values, it doesn't work. I can't seem to find a good way to do that. If twig worked inside of a javascript, just like it does in html, it would look like this:

```
{{ % for team in grades.teams %  }}
name: {{ team.name |json_encode()|raw }},
data: {{ team.members[0].grades |json_encode()|raw }}
{{ % endfor % }}
```

Of course this does not work. How would I achieve it?

I tried this

```
var teams = {{ grades.teams|json_encode() }};
        function getLectureAverageTeam(t, l) //team and lecture
        {
            average=0;
            marks=0;
            for (i = 1; i<t.members.length; i++)
            {
                if (typeof arrayName[index] === 'undefined')
                {}
                else {
                    average += t.members[i].grades[l];
                    marks++;

                }
            }
            average=average/marks;
            return average;
        }
```

Then the code in highcharts: (I know, currently I'm using just one variable, but it works with one number if written manually)

```
 series: [{
                          name: 'Terminal Noobs',
                          data: getLectureAverageTeam(teams[1], 2)
                      },
                      {
                          name: 'Second Team',
                          data: 1
                       }]
```

It only gives an empty screen with no charts.

EDIT: I tried with "var teams" and without var. Nothing really works.

EDIT2: I am really stupid -_-

Changed

```
typeof arrayName[index] === 'undefined'
```

to

```
typeof t.members[i].grades[l] === 'undefined'
```

But I still get the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, write an inline `<script>`, that populates a variable with `grades.teams`, then loop over that variable in your JS highcharts code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    teams = {{ grades.teams|json_encode() }};
</script>
```

Comment: How would I do that? (sorry, I am a newb to all of this)

I need to get average grade of specific lecture. So, my code actually looks like this:

Sorry, I can't put code here. I'll update the question.

Comment: What is the contents of `teams`?